# Can't receive any data from websocket - Only "sleeping to keep loop open"

Tags: python, api, websocket, kucoin

When using the sample code in the wiki of `python-kucoin`:
https://python-kucoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websockets.html

I keep on getting `"sleeping to keep loop open"` while in debug mode (I am using PyCharm).

Digging into the code, I also realized that at this stage of the code `(res['instanceServers'][0]['endpoint'])`:
https://github.com/sammchardy/python-kucoin/blob/develop/kucoin/client.py#L183

the enpoint is
`wss://ws-api.kucoin.com/endpoint`

while according from Kucoin documentation it should be:
`wss://push1-v2.kucoin.com/endpoint`

Is this expected?

I forced the code to change this but it doesn't help receiving any data either...

How long am I supposed to wait before receiving any data from the websocket?

Answer (score 0):

Most of SammChardy's Kucoin Python package hasn't been updated in years. The other one at:

https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-python-sdk

Looks very much similar to SammChardy's but is updated more regularly. I tried both and settled on the latter one. Give it a go and see if it'll resolve your issues.